# How to sync data between different devices sharing same account in firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am using Firebase database and I have app like "google keep"
when user put data I will save data in sqfLite then if the user is Connected to the Network I will 
save data in Firebase with Milliseconds and save same Milliseconds on device 
then next time when user add data I see if Milliseconds on Firebase = Milliseconds on device if that true I add change to Firebase if not I get data from Firebase.
I think this way have some error.
is there better way to do that ?

Comment: No, this will work fine.
Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50471309/how-to-listen-for-document-changes-in-cloud-firestore-using-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Firestore database is meant to be in sync all across the devices for a particular user. You can either do the comparison manually or simply put a listener. A listener will automatically push the data whenever user logs in from a new device keeping the data consistent all across.

[This](https://youtu.be/DqJ_KjFzL9I) is a quick video demonstrating how to achieve 'automatic' sync all across the devices. All you need to add is the user/account filter.