# How can I listen only to doc that changed in Firestore stream?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following `Firestore` stream:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").orderBy("timestamp", descending: true).snapshots().listen((value) async{
   // here i noticed if doc was added or updated so the stream will take action to all docs 
   in that collection
  });
```

For example if i write `.set()` to same collection like following:

```
.set({
 name : 'Alex'
});
```

and I had another doc with the field name 'jack' then I used the following in the previous stream:

```
stream...{
if(value['name]=='Alex'){
print('ok');
}
if(value['name]=='jack'){
print('ok'); // ok here should print 'ok' if it first snapshot , 
but it will always print 'ok' whatever the new doc equal 
my condition or not
}
}
```

How can I only listen to doc that newly added or updated or changed ?

Comment: Are you looking for [`docChanges`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docChanges.html) as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50471309/13130697) ? This returns an array of the documents that changed since the last snapshot

Comment: To listen to only one last saved document, add `limitTo(1)` method to whole stream chain. With no limits, you will get all or max 100 documents in one stream.

Comment: Hi @Jack, was my answer helpful ?

Comment: too late , but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dharmaraj recommended,  [docChanges()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot/docChanges.html) method informs us of all the changes that have occurred in our database.

`docChanges()` method should be used on the snapshot parameter. Since that gives an array of document changes, we iterate over with a loop. If you make a console.log of the local variable of the loop, you will see that this returns each change (in the form of an object).

Example:

```
db.collection('recipes').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
    // console.log(snapshot.docChanges());
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
        console.log(change);
    });
});
```

Do not forget that docChanges() should always be a function and never an array.

Additionally, you can add server [timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp). You can set a server timestamp in a field in your document to track when the server receives the update.

Each field receives the same server timestamp value when several timestamp fields are updated during a transaction.