# Combine multiple where condition and listen the cloud data changes

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using two "where" conditions to retrieve the data from Firestore (same checks are configured in the Firestore rules). I can access the data without any issue if its just one time, like below.

```
      var collection = ref.collection(Constants.Environment)
      .doc("data")
      .collection("groups");

  List<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> queries = [];

  if(phone != null) {
    queries = await Future.wait([
      collection.where("user_list.$phone", isNotEqualTo: "").get(),
      collection.where("org_id", isEqualTo: phone).get(),
    ]);
  }
  
  for(int i = 0; i< queries.length; i++){
    var query = queries[i];
```

Now, I need to listen for add/remove in the "groups" collection. I am aware of listening changes if there is no "where" condition. But it has the "where" condition to filter the data, not sure whether it's possible or not.

Comment: I need to use multiple where conditions as mentioned in the question.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-query-filter-compound-multi-eq

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.snapshots()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html) to listen to changes.

You code would look something like:

```dart
var collection = ref.collection(Constants.Environment)
    .doc("data")
    .collection("groups");

if(phone != null) {
    var query1 = collection.where("user_list.$phone", isNotEqualTo: "");
    var query2 = collection.where("org_id", isEqualTo: phone);

    query1.snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
        for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
           ...
        }
    });
}
```

**Notes:**

- You might want to use a [`StreamBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html).
- If you want to listen to combine *both* streams into one, you can try: [Flutter merge two firestore streams into a single stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53287717/12349734) (not tested.)

**See also**

- [How to listen for document changes in Cloud Firestore using Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50471309/12349734)